# Receiving error response with the code 368 on replying to comment via Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph API to send replies to the post comments in my page where suddenly it started throwing the below exception with the error code 368. But I am able to post the comments directly from the Facebook page.

> "You're temporarily restricted from liking posts, Pages and comments,
>   and from reviewing Pages. This is because there's been some unusual
>   activity in your account. Your account will be limited until today at
>   7:52 PM."

In Facebook documentation, it's mentioned as a policy violation will cause to throw this error code but there is no detail on what timezone the time in the message is.

Can someone help me in identifying the timezone? Also want to know what my action had caused to block the API calls?

Comment: Not sure if that’s documented anywhere. But you got to wait at most 24 hours to find out in any case :-)

Comment: The Insights API uses US Pacific Time (i.e. that of Facebook's headquarters). It's very possible that things like error message get localized into the requesting account's timezone, though, as they're intended to be relayed to the user.

Answer (score -1):

This error code also happens on Messenger for Desktop and Android. It's is mostly due to the fact that you’ve sent the same message few seconds ago. It happened to me when I was sending the same message to different group chats. Other variation of this error is "You can't reply to this conversation".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63vWE.jpg)

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site in your post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: Just a link to your blog doesn't make for an answer. [Answers must actually answer the question](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), without the requiring the user to click to some other site to get the answer. Please [add context around links](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259). **[Always quote](/help/referencing) the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](/help/deleted-answers).